# HTTP to HTTPS rewrite rule not working

Tags: apache2, mod-rewrite, mod-ssl

ubuntu 14.04

Apache/2.4.7

I am posting here conf file for my virtual host and default ssl host.
not able to figure what am I doing wrong.

`http://<website_url>`      shows the index of the folder. I want to redirect this to https.

`https://<website_url>`     opens fine.

IMPORTANT: I have not enabled the default SSL site.

```
 cat default-ssl.conf|grep -v "#"

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
      <VirtualHost _default_:443>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile  /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key

        <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
                SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
        </FilesMatch>
        <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
                SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
        </Directory>

        BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-6]" \
                nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
                downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
        BrowserMatch "MSIE [17-9]" ssl-unclean-shutdown

        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
        RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
    </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

And here is mywebsite configuration file:

```
cat www.mywebsite.com.conf|grep -v "#"

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName www.mywebsite.com:443
    ServerAlias www.mywebsite.com
    ServerAdmin abc@mywebsite.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/www.mywebsite.com/html

    Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains"
     <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
      RewriteEngine On
      RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
      RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
    </IfModule>

SSLEngine on   
    SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.key

    <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
        SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </FilesMatch>
    <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
        SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </Directory>

    BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-6]" \
        nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
        downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
    BrowserMatch "MSIE [17-9]" ssl-unclean-shutdown

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/ssl.error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/ssl.access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want that `http://www.mywebsite.com/` is always be sent over `https` you should use `redirect` because use `mod_rewrite` isn't the recommended behavior.

According to [**Redirect Request to SSL**](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RedirectSSL) Apache wiki page:

> When using SSL, you will frequently have at least two virtual hosts:
>   one on port 80 to serve ordinary requests, and one on port 443 to
>   serve SSL. If you wish to redirect users from the non-secure site to
>   the SSL site, you can use an ordinary Redirect directive inside the
>   non-secure VirtualHost

So, try to add this directive in your non-secure VirtualHost:

```
Redirect permanent / https://www.mywebsite.com/
```

If you want anyway use `rewrite` rule, you should add these lines in non-secure `VirtualHost`:

```
RewriteEngine On
# This will enable the Rewrite capabilities

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
# This checks to make sure the connection is not already HTTPS

RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
# This rule will redirect users from their original location, to the same location but using HTTPS.
# i.e.  http://www.mywebsite.com/foo/ to https://www.mywebsite.com/foo/
```

as described in [**HTTP to HTTPS**](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteHTTPToHTTPS) Apache wiki page.

---

Your configuration doen't work, because it is not defined a non-secure VirtualHost (usually on port 80) that handles http requests and redirect them to secure VirtualHost.

Try adding these lines:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName dev.dom1.com
   Redirect permanent / https://dev.dom1.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

In this case you don't need a `DocumentRoot` because this `VirtualHost` is redirecting everything.

`Rewrite` rule shown in your configuration file protect secure `VirtualHost` from being accessed via `http` protocol, for example `http://www.mywebsite.com:443/` will be `https://www.mywebsite.com:443/`

You should also check that your site linking to the correct page (https) from within your HTML pages.

Comment: This looks promising. i am running 3 different virtual hosts on same box. 2 are on port 80, and one on 443. Their FQDN are different, but they resolve to same IP and their config files are different. So how can i resolve this?

Comment: You should add directive in those `VirtualHost` that is the same as 443 `VirtualHost`. I guess non-secure `VirtualHost` with `ServerName www.mywebsite.com` and `DocumentRoot /var/www/www.mywebsite.com/html`. If you need to redirect both, you need to define two 443 VirtualHost.

Comment: Hello Letizia, 443 VirtualHost does not have a corresponding VirtualHost. Sites are like this: `http://www.dom1.com, https://dev.dom1.com, and http://www.dom2.com`. All hosted on same apache server. I am scratching my head and pulling my hairs at the moment. sorry, I am just not getting this virtual-host thing.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I didn't understand what you are doing :(. I thought you wanted to change protocol for a certain VirtualHost. Could you explain what is your goal?

Comment: goal is to give https access with authentication to developers, but normal www access for rest of the world. and anybody choosing to go to dev.dom1.com should be presented the https site.

Comment: Let's see if I understand. There are two `VirtualHost` on port 80, one have `ServerName www.dom1.com` and the other have `ServerName www.dom2.com` with different DocumentRoot content. Normal user access these sites with http a see the content. The third `VirtualHost` is on port 443 and `ServerName` is `dev.dom1.com`, developers access this site with https protocol and see `DocumentRoot` content. Please tell me if this assertion are right and what does not work or you can not achieve.

Comment: yes totally correct.
`site 1:
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName www.dom1.com
        ServerAlias www.dom1.com
        ServerAdmin rpxx@xx.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/www.dom1.com/html`
...

`site 2:
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName dev.dom1.com:443
        ServerAlias dev.dom1.com
        ServerAdmin rpxx@xx.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/dev.dom1.com/html`
...

`site 3:
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName www.dom2.com
        ServerAlias www.dom2.com
        ServerAdmin rpxx@xx.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/www.dom2.com/html`
...
 
thx for help @Letizia

Comment: You are welcome, but now, I don't see where is the problem and how can I help you :)

Comment: Maybe you would like that access to `http://dev.dom1.com` are redirected to `https://dev.dom1.com`. Is this what you are trying to do?

Comment: yes. correct.  .

Comment: Answer updated.

Comment: Thank you for sticking to it @Letizia. I created a dummy virtual host with "same name(dev.dom1.com)" with only redirection in it. and that resolved the issue.

Comment: Can't believe this doesn't have more votes!

Answer (score 0):

This is an old post, but in Ubuntu 14.04 the original rewrite works, you just have to change it to:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
</Directory>
```